# How to define general/fall-back error page in web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web.xml, spring-webflow

My Java web app currently maps certain error codes to an error servlet (spring web flow, actually, but that should be besides the point), by doing this in web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/spring/error?error=500</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/spring/error?error=404</location>
</error-page>
```

However, in certain cases the server will still crash and give a stack trace dump of some exceptions to the user. (Running on IBM WebSphere btw). My question then is; is it possible to define a fall-back error page that will be used if all other errors don't match? So that we're guaranteed not to end up with a stack trace under any circumstance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the following:

```
<error-page> 
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type> 
    <location>/error.jsp</location> 
</error-page>
```

See http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/codesnippet/servlets/HandlingServletExceptions/HandlingServletExceptions.html for more info.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I was looking for.